# How to represent forum's relationship in Class diagram

Tags: inheritance, associations, uml, composition, class-diagram

I'm trying to make class diagram for a simple forum and i don't understand how to represent it.

Here's what i did:
[image: Forum Class Diagram] 
Firstly, I don't understand how to make relationship between users,posts and threads.

Secondly, is inheritance right choice or Association ??

Comment: This looks good to me.  Perhaps the association between Posts and Members should be bidirectional so that given a post, you can find the member.  There is no inheritance in the diagram and it is not necessary.  What specifically is your issue with the 3 classes you mention?

Comment: 1-there is inheritance in the diagram that arrow from admin to moderator thats how MVS does it. 2- i want to make sure that it is correct or is there a better way to do it b4 start coding

Comment: Ahh indeed.  Not clear of the roles between admin and moderator, but model still looks good enough to begin coding (or generating).

Comment: ah the idea is the higher the rank the more features u can do so  moderator is a member with more access etc